# Pandas scatterplot to plotly figure without interactivity

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly

I wonder if it is somehow possible with plotly/cufflink to convert a pandas.plotting scatterplot matrix to a plotly figure which i can use in dash app without interactivity because it is to resource consuming.

So i create a scatterplot matrix like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix

ax2 = scatter_matrix(selectedPoints,color='Red', alpha=0.8, figsize=(20, 20), diagonal='hist')
```

And get a scatterplot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used dash, but I have used plotly, and according to the [documentation for dash](https://dash.plot.ly/getting-started):

> "The figure argument in the dash_core_components.Graph component is the same figure argument that is used by plotly.py, Plotly's open source Python graphing library."

Since plotly has a native [scatter plot matrix obj](https://plot.ly/python/splom/), and it looks a lot slicker than the pandas scatter plot matrix,
 I suggest trying the code below adapted from the dash and plotly scatter plot matrix documentation. I've set `hoverinfo='skip'` and `dragmode=None` and `hovermode=None` to limit interactivity. The only thing I wasn't able to duplicate from your example were histograms on the diagonal. Obviously for your data you would need to add to the dimensions however many columns you want in your matrix.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

df = pd.DataFrame(selectedPoints)


app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(
        id='SPloM-selectedPoints',
        figure={
            'data': [
                go.Splom(dimensions=[dict(label=df.columns[0],
                                 values=df.iloc[:, 0]),
                            dict(label=df.columns[1],
                                 values=df.iloc[:, 1]),
                            dict(label=df.columns[2],
                                 values=df.iloc[:, 2]),
                            dict(label=df.columns[3],
                                 values=df.iloc[:, 3])],
                text=None,
                marker=dict(color='rgb(255,0,0)',
                            size=7,
                            showscale=False,
                            line=dict(width=0.5,
                                      color='rgb(230,230,230)')), 
                hoverinfo= 'skip')
            ],
            'layout': [
            go.Layout(title='Selected Points',
                dragmode=None,
                width=600,
                height=600,
                autosize=True,
                hovermode=None,
                plot_bgcolor='rgba(240,240,240, 0.95)',
                xaxis1=dict(axis),
                xaxis2=dict(axis),
                xaxis3=dict(axis),
                xaxis4=dict(axis),
                yaxis1=dict(axis),
                yaxis2=dict(axis),
                yaxis3=dict(axis),
                yaxis4=dict(axis)
                )
            ]
        }
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

The output I got on a simple data set looked like this:
[Scatter Plot Matrix from Plotly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIsrC.png)